# Cannot start mysql: InnoDB: Upgrade after a crash is not supported

Tags: mysql, homebrew, innodb

I am trying to run MySQL from a Homebrew installation, but it keeps failing when trying `mysql.server start`.

My `/usr/local/var/mysql/<name>.local.err` reads as so, and keeps sending this error message every few seconds.

```
2018-06-20T20:38:54.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/<computer name>.local.err'.
2018-06-20T20:38:54.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2018-06-20T20:38:54.379228Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.11) starting as process 6271
2018-06-20T20:38:54.383128Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2018-06-20T20:38:54.449869Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012526] [InnoDB] InnoDB: Upgrade after a crash is not supported. This redo log was created with MySQL 5.7.20. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html
2018-06-20T20:38:54.449947Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2018-06-20T20:38:54.919197Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2018-06-20T20:38:54.919769Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2018-06-20T20:38:54.919814Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2018-06-20T20:38:54.920978Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.11)  Homebrew.
2018-06-20T20:38:54.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/bae.local.pid ended
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had the exact same errors in my log. Just to build off Nipponese' answer.

**Remove all versions of MySQL** (I had 5.7.21, 5.7.22, and 8.0.11) :

`brew uninstall --force mysql`

**Confirm Removal and Repair** :

`brew services list` and then `brew doctor`

**Rename original MySQL** :

`mv /usr/local/var/mysql /usr/local/var/old.mysql`

**Install latest MySQL** (currently 8.0.11) :

`brew install mysql`

**MySQL Secure Install** :

`/usr/local/bin/mysql_secure_installation`

I initially received this error: `Error: Access denied for user 'dbadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I'm using a user level config. So I **renamed .my.cnf** and ran the secure install again.

`mv /Users/[your username]/.my.cnf /Users/[your username]/old.my.cnf`
`/usr/local/bin/mysql_secure_installation`

On the install prompts I input the following options `Y, 0, Y, N, N, Y, Y`.

**Upgrade MySQL Workbench**
After that I still couldn't connect with MySQL Workbench (GA 6.3.10) although it did appear to be starting MySQL finally. I was getting the following error prompt.

"Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found"

To resolve this I downloaded MySQL Workbench 8.0.11 rc (the Development Release version). I used the GUI to add the users I had before adhering to the new password rules. I updated and renamed ~/.my.cnf with the more secure password. Then restored my DBs.

At this point I was able to connect with workbench using root and the new password I setup during the secure install.

**Clean Up** (remove renamed directory and it's contents) :

`rm -r /usr/local/var/old.mysql`

Comment: Perhaps it was already self-answered, but not with such essential detail for those of us looking for the exact steps needed.

Comment: What is the purpose of renaming `/usr/local/var/mysql` rather than simply removing it at the outset? `old.mysql` isn't used anywhere except during the clean up step.

I ask because it would be helpful to reinstall MySQL while preserving the databases.

Comment: The reason I did it was just in case I wanted any of the data later. All my local databases were/are clones of our production environment so I didn't back anything up and just synced it all after the upgrade process. I believe you could use the databases from previous versions although mysql 8 has updated encryption rules for passwords. I know you can add a line to your .my.cnf to use the older auth method instead of sha2. Sorry I'm not super knowledgable on that part. I hope this helps.

Comment: If you get `Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)` while running `/usr/local/bin/mysql_secure_installation`, you may need to simply start the MySql server like I did.  You can do this by running "mysql.server start".

Comment: This is a bad answer. Reinstalling software and loosing all data is like buying a new car instead of repairing it

Answer (score 12):

tldr; A new version of mysql was installed via Homebrew. Revert to the previously installed version.

```
brew switch mysql X.X.XX` and `brew services restart mysql
```

---

The full story is that you likely installed a newer version of mysql with `brew upgrade`.  Review the output of `brew info mysql`.  You may see more than one version.

In my case, I saw both of the following:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11
```

I checked `mysql --version` and the newer 8.0.11 was running.

Homebrew includes the `switch` command that allows you to do just that between services.

Execute this replacing the version with your own:

```
brew switch mysql 5.7.17
```

Restart mysql:

```
brew services restart mysql
```

All should be back in working order.

Comment: Good answer. Worked for me

Comment: If /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.* is removed, restore it from time machine.

Comment: Too bad I didn't find this before I uninstalled every version of mysql. FML

Comment: Here `brew switch` returns an error: `Error: Unknown command: switch`

Answer (score 2):

I looks like the issue was a previous installation in `/usr/local/var/mysql`.

After uninstalling via homebrew, removing `/usr/local/var/mysql`, running `brew doctor`, and re-installing via homebrew, the issue went away.

Comment: Will removing `/usr/local/var/mysql` remove all your database content?

Comment: @Nicodemuz yup.

Comment: you should probably highlight that as a warning!